# Moving to UK under Tier 2 General Visa – Can I switch employers easily?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

Since I'll be moving there on a work visa, what happens in the event that I get a better job offer from a different company than I work for? Can I just submit my notice, serve the notice period and then quit and go work for another company? Should I stay with the employer for a specific period of time before I can switch employers?

I ask this because I currently live in Qatar. The employers actively restrict them from quitting and working elsewhere. If one jumps jobs, it is a crime punishable by immediate deportation. What's the law in UK? Can the employers force penalties in case the workforce wants to leave?

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, it is not a crime to quit your job. If you do not honor your contract (i.e., notice period), you can be responsible for "damages". Your employment rights are governed by UK and EU labor laws and are not affected by the fact that your are an expat. At the point at which you quit your job, the UKBA will potentially [curtail your leave to remain](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/514054/Tier_2_Policy_Guidance_04_2016.pdf). If the UKBA decides to curtail your leave, you will have 60 days to leave the UK, so "immediate deportation" should not be a concern.

As far as switching employers, it is a little more complicated. You will need to apply to [extend your visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/extend-your-visa). This requires you to still be employed by your "previous/current" sponsor. You cannot quit your current job and then look for work during the 60 days you have to leave and still apply for an extension. Nor can you Tier 2 have expired. Your new employer will have to generate a certificate of sponsorship (just like your current employer did). Once you have that, you can apply to extend your Tier 2. Once you have your Tier 2, you can serve your notice period and then finally start your new job.

Answer (score -2):

Well this is such a grey area in immigration rules,it is no where specified to as one can serve notice period with previous employer after getting new tier-2 visa which is issued with new employer so ideally you are breaching the law.